Is complete matter decay strictly necessary for Conformal Cyclic Cosmology to work?
I know that CCC is highly speculative and not widely accepted but I am curious about the constraints of this idea. As I understand it, CCC is the idea that in a massless universe, time and distance lose definite scaling and become conformally equivalent to a tiny hot universe. Any massive particles introduce definite scale and will prevent this transition between aeons. (I was also wondering about quantum fluctuations necessarily creating spontaneous mass over deep time and I’d like to explore if that prevents CCC from working too.)
My question is that even if massive particles remain after “heat death”, e.g. protons never decay or if electrons never lose their mass, if the universe keeps expanding won’t there necessarily eventually be regions of space completely devoid of mass out to their own event horizons? Since these regions would be completely causally separate from any region with mass, would this then allow the conformal mapping to the next aeon in this region?

I think I see the connection with the question and the body but maybe you should make it more clear how you are connecting proton decay to CCC in the body of the question just to make it more obvious to a wider audience.

Caveat: I don't work on CCC, am not an expert, and don't claim to understand it very well. I have listed to some talks and read a few papers about it.
From what I understood reading the Introduction and Sections 1-3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.10864, is that the basic idea of CCC is to use a conformal symmetry of the asymptotic timelike boundary of de Sitter space to map the far future of our Universe to the far past of a new Universe. Because the symmetry is defined over the timelike boundary of de Sitter, the symmetry involves regions which are spacelike separated, and in particular different "Hubble patches" (regions which are separated by a cosmological horizon). So, I don't think it's good enough to say that one patch of the Universe looks conformal so we can apply CCC; the boundary of the patch will break the conformal symmetry. One concrete effect of only having conformal symmetry in one patch of the spacelike surface, is that when you map it to the far past, it won't cover the whole Universe, so as the new Universe evolves you will be able to receive signals from the boundary of that patch, whereas a manifold shouldn't have any boundary.
However, since the symmetry is based on matching the background metric in the far future to one in the far past, it may be that it's ok to have small fluctuations that don't contribute significantly to the background. In practical terms, that would mean that having a few massive particles around may not break the CCC idea so long as they do not contribute significantly to the overall energy budget of the Universe, compared to a radiation fluid. It sounds like one reason not to want significant numbers of massive particles (besides manifestly breaking conformal invariance) is that they will dominate the energy budget of the Universe at late times, compared to a photon fluid. The idea that "a small amount" of massive particles is consistent with CCC is also stated on Wikipedia

In his Nobel Prize Lecture video, Roger Penrose moderated his previous requirement for no mass, beginning at 26:30 in the video, allowing some mass particles to be present as long as the amounts are insignificant with nearly all of their energy being kinetic, and in a conformal geometry dominated by photons.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology#Basic_construction
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpPFn0qzYT0/&t=26m30s


Thank you for your response. So when you say “so as the new Universe evolves you will be able to receive signals from the boundary of that patch, whereas a manifold shouldn't have any boundary”, you mean that if that region of causally separate space, the Hubble patch, were to conformally rescale, it would then not necessarily be causally separate from regions formerly beyond the horizon (due to the rescaling), so it’s not possible?

@ZoonvanZaal I don't see how it could be. Initially it would presumably be causally disconnected from spacelike separated points, but as time evolves you should start to see signals from those points, analogous to how modes re-enter the horizon during inflation. At least that's what I would expect if you had a period of radiation domination following the CCC phase.

in Penrose diagram language, the Penrose diagram for de Sitter spacetime is a square. The reason there's a cosmological horizon in the late Universe is that light cones can't be continued past the top of the square, so there are regions of spacetime that you can't send a signal to. However, if the idea of CCC is to match the late Universe to an early Universe, then I would imagine the Penrose diagram becomes more like stacked squares, so that the light rays continue past the "top" of the square and then come out the "bottom" of the next square. So the cosmological horizon kind of goes away.
